# How do start network settings in Debian Raspberry PI in a non-root user

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, raspberry-pi

Every time I log in to my user account "bob" I have to use these commands (with sudo or in the root account) to connect to the WiFi:

```
wpa_supplicant -B -D wext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
dhclient wlan0
```

`wpa_supplicant -B -D wext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` gives me this result :

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Could not set interface wlan0 flags (UP): Operation not permitted
WEXT: Could not set interface 'wlan0' UP
wlan0: Failed to initialized driver interface
```

And for `dhclient wlan0` I get:

```
RTNETLINK answers: Operation is unreachable
```

I am doing this on a Raspberry PI 4 with Debian 10 Codename: buster.

I have systemd.

How do I set up my environment so that every time I boot up, or I log in with "bob" or even root, my system connects to the WiFi?

I was thinking of using the commands I just showed and put them in .profile but I cannot run them with the "bob" account.

Answer (score 1):

Your wifi credentials go to `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`.

The file should look like

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
country=US
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="<wifi name>"
    psk="<wifi password>"
}
```

The Pi will now autoconnect on every boot (or when in reach of the wifi). To reload the wifi after applying the changes, use `sudo systemctl restart dhcpdc`. You may add more `network=` blocks if you have several wifis you regularly connect to.

You may also remove the SD card and place a file `wpa_supplicant.conf` with the above content in the `/boot`-section of the SD to load it on a fresh install of Raspberry Pi OS.

Answer (score 1):

A cron job to run the desired commands for you.

Create a script `autocnnect.sh`:

```
cat <<EOF > autoconnect.sh
/usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -B -D wext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
sleep 0.5
/usr/sbin/dhclient wlan0 >/dev/null 2>&1
EOF
```

make it executable

```
chmod +x autoconnect.sh
```

As root, run `crontab -e` then add the following line:

```
@reboot /path/to/autoconnect.sh
```